# How to loop audio when mixing with longer movie in avconv

Tags: ubuntu, libav

Is it possible to loop audio when mixing with longer movie using avconv?
I want music to repeat itself through whole movie.
In avconv manual i found parameter "-flags loop" but it doesn't work. 
Music plays once and stops, while movie lasts longer with no sound.

```
avconv -i LONGER_MOVIE.mpg -i SHORTER.mp3 -flags loop -map 0:v -map 1:a MIXED_OUTPUT.mpg
```

Comment: `-flags loop` shouldn't exist in recent Libav as far as I know. Also, the `-loop` option only works for images. I don't think what you want is currently possible. You could duplicate the MP3 separately from the video track, and then use the `-shortest` option.

Comment: Thanks. That's what i've actually done. It's not the best solution, because i want server script to mix short loopped music with video uploaded by users. To use that technique i have to make music file at least 2 hours long (in case of my audios repeat them about 60 times). I hoped there is a better method.